# Correct use of boost lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-lambda

Consider the following piece of C++0x code:

```
a_signal.connect([](int i) {
  if(boost::any_cast<std::string>(_buffer[i]) == "foo")
  {
    base_class<>* an_object = new derived_class();
    an_object->a_method(_buffer[i]);
  }});
```

How would it correctly look in Boost Lambda (since this C++0x feature can't be used in GCC 4.4 yet)?

Comment: You *can* use C++0x feature if the compiler supports it.

Comment: OMG, the pain! Make it stop! (Good question, though.)

Comment: @KennyTM I've GCC 4.4 and it doesn't support it yet. GCC 4.5 supports it (afaik) but I can't use it. I'll edit the question ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
a_signal.connect(if_then(
                  bind((std::string(*)(any&))&any_cast, var(_buffer)[_1]) == "foo",
                   bind(&base_class<>::a_method, 
                    ll_static_cast< base_class<>* >(
                     new_ptr<derived_class>()
                    ), 
                    var(_buffer)[_1]
                   )
                 )
);
```

`bind`, `if_then`, `ll_static_cast`, `new_ptr`, `_1`, `var` (and, i think `ref` too) are members of `boost::lambda`.

But honestly, i would refuse to work with such code, personally :)

Comment: thanks. I'll be really happy if I can use C++0x fully :). With your solution I get `no match for operator[]` in the lines where `_buffer[_1]` is called .. but the `operator[]` exists in the buffer class. Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Niels, i forgot to wrap them in `var(..)`. Fixed :)

Comment: Now In the line `boost::bind(&any_cast<string>, boost::ref(var(_buffer)[lambda::_1])) == "foo"`, I get a no matching function call for `bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::reference_wrapper ...`. I have `boost/lambda/bind.hpp` included and the other bind call doesn't fail ...

Comment: @Niels, you need to cast. fixed

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: It slowly becomes embarrasing for me ... no it says no matching function call for `if_then`. But `boost/lambda/if.hpp` is included ...

Comment: +1 for refusal to work with such code.  I agree, it's not just that I wouldn't write code like that, I would never allow code like that through a code review (unless of course I was overruled, but you get the point).